# clockwork gem logger not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

I'm using the clockwork gem to a mange scheduled jobs.
Everything works great except that I could have the logs write to a file.

here's my initializer:

```
module Clockwork
  configure do |config|
    config[:logger] = Logger.new("clockwork.log")
  end
end
```

and when I started clockwork, I still see the logs on stdout:

```
$ clockwork config/clock.rb
I, [2014-06-12T12:43:12.029169 #12396]  INFO -- : Starting clock for 1 events: [ sync_database_tasks_for_model_ScheduledJob ]
I, [2014-06-12T12:43:12.029278 #12396]  INFO -- : Triggering 'sync_database_tasks_for_model_ScheduledJob'
I, [2014-06-12T12:43:13.123395 #12396]  INFO -- : Triggering 'Winnie Test'
```

the clockwork.log was created, but there weren't any logs written.
I could work around by redirect the output on my unix command, but I'd like to make it work the way it should be.